# Finding a good practice: global variables or something else?

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm making a graphical application using GLFW.
And... I need to handle GLFW callbacks in a specific way somehow. For example, handling framebuffer size callback. I need to route this event to my Application class:

```cpp
class OglApplication
{
/* Rest is ommited. */

public:
    void Init();

    void Render();
    void OnResize(int width, int height);
    void OnDestroy();
};
```

```cpp
OglApplication app;
```

`glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback` function accepts a function ptr with this signature:

```cpp
void framebuffer_onSizeChanged(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
```

So I need to create an intermediate function that will adapt it to `void OnResize(int width, int height);`. Anyway I can't pass it directly because `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback` accepts only static functions (miss C# delegates ).

So... what did I try?
I tried to use global variables but I know that it's considered bad practice.

I could use a global map (key=GLFWwindow, value=OglApplication) and just get the OglApplication by its associated GLFWwindow. But actually in my application I have only one window and only one OglApplication instance. So I could just write a global pointer:

```cpp
static OglApplication* app;
```

And use it within the callback. I even declared it as static, so it can be accessed only in the current translation unit, thus other code won't violate the state (one of the arguments against global vars). Is it still bad?

I've also tried to write lambda expression. This works:

```cpp
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(mainWindow, [](GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
        {

        });
```

However I need to use OglApplication (which is local variable) in there. And this:

```cpp
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(mainWindow, [&](GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
        {
            app.OnResize(width, height);
        });
```

... doesn't work. The compiler reports an error when I'm trying to capture something.

So how I need to do this? Using global map/pointer? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`glfwSetWindowUserPointer`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651) and [`glfwGetWindowUserPointer`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#gae77a4add0d2023ca21ff1443ced01653) functions to associate the `GLFWwindow*` with whatever state you need, for example, a pointer to your `OglApplication`. The user pointer is [guaranteed not to be touched by GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_userptr); it is entirely up to you to use, as the user.

In your callbacks, you will need to cast the getter's result from `void*` back to `OglApplication*`.

The reason it has to work like this is because GLFW is a C library, and lambda's with captures are a C++ feature. Lambda's *without* captures are also a C++ feature, but they can be converted to function pointers, which do exist in C.

Comment: And with that the non-capturing version of the lambda will work, which can be converted to a simple function pointer.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: But how I should deal with libraries that doesn't provide such functionality with associating "user pointer"? What is the best practice for these scenarios?

Comment: @Daniel Then global variables are the only sane solution. But any half-decent libraries include user pointers, the lack of it should be reported as a bug.